How can I calculate the distribution of a project cost according to execution date in Python?
I´m working on an energy investment projects dataframe (DF). In this DF, I have two datetime type columns with 'initial_data' and 'final_data' and one float type column 'total_cost'.
I need to create columns according to how much of this project is executed each year, using days as a proxy.
For example: project 1:
\\>\>\> 'initial_data' = 2013-07-01 

\\>\>\> 'final_data' = 2015-06-30 

\\>\>\> 'total_cost' = 2,000.00


For the given project, i need to create 3 columns and I should get the following results respectivelly:
\\>\>\> 'total_cost_2013' = 500.00 

\\>\>\> 'total_cost_2014' = 1,000.00 

\\>\>\> 'total_cost_2015' = 500.00\`

I´m really struggling to do this. Does someone have a simple solution for that?
I expect to have the cost of the project for each year, according to the proportion of how many days in the year this project is executed.

IIUC, you can use the approach below.
In summary, loop through all the years present in the dataframe, get the number of days the project was executed in each year, then add a corresponding column with the proportional cost for the year.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "initial_data": ["2013-07-01"],
        "final_data": ["2015-06-30"],
        "total_cost": [2000.0],
    }
)

df[["initial_data", "final_data"]] = df[["initial_data", "final_data"]].apply(
    pd.to_datetime
)

years = np.arange(df["initial_data"].dt.year.min(), df["final_data"].dt.year.max() + 1)

yearly_costs = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index)

for year in years:
    start_of_year = pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-01-01")
    end_of_year = pd.to_datetime(f"{year}-12-31")

    year_start = df["initial_data"].clip(lower=start_of_year, upper=end_of_year)
    year_end = df["final_data"].clip(lower=start_of_year, upper=end_of_year)

    days_in_year = (year_end - year_start).dt.days
    days_in_year = np.where(
        (year_end.dt.year >= df["initial_data"].dt.year)
        | (year_end.dt.year <= df["final_data"].dt.year),
        days_in_year + 1,
        days_in_year,
    )
    total_days = (df["final_data"] - df["initial_data"]).dt.days + 1

    yearly_cost = df["total_cost"] * (days_in_year / total_days)
    yearly_cost = yearly_cost.where(days_in_year > 0, 0)

    yearly_costs[f"total_cost_{year}"] = yearly_cost

out = pd.concat([df, yearly_costs.loc[:, (yearly_costs != 0).any(axis=0)]], axis=1)

  initial_data final_data  total_cost  total_cost_2013  total_cost_2014  total_cost_2015
0   2013-07-01 2015-06-30      2000.0       504.109589           1000.0       495.890411


I appreciate a lot your answer.
If you were writing a code like that to be updated every year, when new projects with new initial data and final data would also needed to be included. Also, this dataframe should be inserted in a SQLite database.
Would you separate the projetcts yearly cost by columns or by lines?

Definitely lines. I'd normalize the data, so create one table for the project info (name, initial_date, final_date etc.) and another table for project costs (cost, year, and a foreign key to the project table). So each new project would be a line added to the first table, and each new yearly cost would be a line on the second table.

be careful with "total_cost_2014", it may mean Fin Year, - the period from 2013-07-01 to 2014-06-30 and not the calendar year as per example
